# CakePHP 3 and ACL plug in

Tags: cakephp, plugins, controls, acl

I am trying to make a simple ACL using CakePHP 3, and there are no tutorials for it in the cook book (only for cakephp 2 and now acl doesn't exist in cakephp3)

Question 1
I am trying to install the acl plugin from https://github.com/cakephp/acl, how may I do that?

Question 2
Is there any comprehensive and beginner friendly tutorial on how to make an ACL on CakePHP3? I've trying searching everywhere, but found nothing. If anyone could guide me on how to do a simple one it would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

USE  cakephp-3acl-example project to creating permission and granding permission for users

https://github.com/mattmemmesheimer/cakephp-3-acl-example

Answer (score 1):

> Question 1 I am trying to install the acl plugin from https://github.com/cakephp/acl, how may I do that?

Like any other plugin? [See the documentation.](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html)

The readme.md itself contains instructions as well but also a warning:

> Note: This is a **non-stable** plugin for CakePHP 3.0 at this time. It is
> currently under development and should be considered experimental.

Maybe try it and provide feedback to the developers?

> Question 2 Is there any comprehensive and beginner friendly tutorial on how to make an ACL on CakePHP3? I've trying searching everywhere, but found nothing.
>
> If anyone could guide me on how to do a simple one it would be much appreciated.

ACL is always the same, if you know how ACL works you can implement it in any language and framework. If you don't know how, read about how ACL in general works.

But a better idea might to simply use the plugin you already found and help testing and completing it if you encounter issues.

Comment: "ACL is always the same, if you know how ACL works you can implement it in any language and framework. If you don't read about how ACL in general works."

Maybe because this is not an answer?

Answer (score -2):

burzum is correct that the installation instructions and documentation are available at https://github.com/cakephp/acl .

I am cutting over from a 1.3 implementation so have not gone through setting up a new acl database.

I have not seen a comprehensive doc on how to setup ACL, the 'short' version I have in my notes is:

1) setup 'Auth' as per the blog example (yes Auth is not ACL but this is what I am using it for)
2) install ACL using composer
3) override 'isAuthorized' in AppController with a check like:

```
...
use Acl\Controller\Component\AclComponent;
use Cake\Controller\ComponentRegistry;
...
public function isAuthorized($user){
      $Collection = new ComponentRegistry();
      $acl= new AclComponent($Collection);
      $username=$user['username'];
      $controller=$this->request->controller;
      $action=$this->request->action;
      $check=$acl->check($user['username'],"$controller/$action");
      return $check;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can follow this plugin.

[CakePhp3-AclManager](https://github.com/JcPires/CakePhp3-AclManager)

And the tutorial (step by step) [here](http://qiita.com/eiroh/items/f37a70a35103de6c6a1b)

If you don't know Japan language, use google translate.

Good luck.